# Need help on writing automated REST API tests ? How can I improve?

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, testng

I'm trying to improve writing functional automated tests for my REST API's

Here is a sample:

Q1 Can someone critic my tests or see if there is room for improvements?

Q2 Also I'm planning to write a series of API tests in the AppTest class...Is there a way or a function or utility where I can store the responses in a file or something as I execute a series of API tests ?

```
 package com.jaway.restassured.rest_assured;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get;

import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;


import com.jayway.restassured.response.*;

public class AppTest {

    String url = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/";

    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public void getRequestFindCapital(String country, String expected_capital, String expected_region, String expected_trans_it ) throws JSONException{

        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        //Make a request to fetch the capital of norway
        Response resp = get(url + country);
        System.out.println(url + country);
        JSONArray jsonResponse =new JSONArray(resp.asString());
        System.out.println(resp.asString());

        //Declare variables
        String actual_capital = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).getString("capital"); 
        String actual_region = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).getString("region");
        List<Object> actual_translations = resp.jsonPath().getList("translations.it");
        String actual_translations_string  = actual_translations.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
        System.out.println(actual_translations);
        System.out.println(actual_translations_string);

        softAssert.assertEquals(actual_capital, expected_capital);
        softAssert.assertEquals(actual_region, expected_region);
        softAssert.assertEquals(actual_translations_string, expected_trans_it);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

     @DataProvider
         public Object[][] getData() {
             return new Object[][]{
                 {"Norway", "Oslo","Europe", "Norvegia"}, 
                 {"Britain", "London","Europe","Regno Unito"}, 
                 {"Bangladesh","Dhaka","Asia","Bangladesh"}};
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually write my ITests in OpenEJB or Arquillian. With OpenEJB the test class can start an embedded container before launch the tests. You can view examples here: http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/index.html. Is JEE6 compliant, JEE7 is not released yet...

Comment: Now is JEE7 compliant

Answer (score 0):

1. You are going only to the happy path. So to improve your tests you may want to add some wrong input and verify that you will receive the proper error. For example you can provide the not existing country and verify the answer. 
   In this way you may add few functional tests.
   I would suggest also add few nonfunctional tests like performance in order to measure your REST latency.
2. There are few utilities that allow to save the REST calls and responses. My favorite is PostMan which plugin to Chrome (just search in the Chrome store).

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to check out [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io) framework for writing functional tests, it simplifies writing test cases a lot. I personally feel like JUnit or TestNG are only suitable for unit tests where there's need for stubbing/mocking.

You will be able to write test cases in plain English like:

```
Feature: Countries API
  Scenario: Retrieve Capital City
    Given the specified country is "United States"
    When I make the API request
    Then the response should be valid JSON
     And it should contain property "city" with value "Washington, D.C."
```

And then you can write implementation for those English sentences using any Cucumber implementation. My favorite in this case is Node.js but they have several implementations. The advantage of this approach is now you can have even non-technical members of the team write end-to-end test cases.